# Twig variable in external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, external

I would like to externalize my JS code, but there is Twig variable in the code.
What are your tricks to make this working?

```
team: {{ 'Select your team'|trans }}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There a two approaches when you need to pass a twig variable to an external javascript file

1. Define the variables inside a script block in the twig template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <script>
           var my_twig_var = {% if twig_var is defined %}'{{ twig_var }}'{% else %}null{% endif %}
       </script>
       <script src="scripts/functions.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

For this approach I usally add a block called "javascript" block in my main/base template

*base.twig.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       {% block body %}
       {% endblock %}
       {% block javascript %}
       {% endblock %}
   </body>
</html>
```

*page.html.twig*

```html
{% extends base.twig.html %}
{% block body%}
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script>
      alert('{{ twig_var|default('Hello World') }}');
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

---

2. Pass the variables to javascript with the aid of `data-*` attributes

```html
<div data-foo="{{ foo }}">...</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.button', function(e) {
        console.log($('div[data-foo]').data('foo'));
    });
});
```

---

Sidenote: if you want to pass an object or an array to `twig` you can always use the `json_encode` filter, which will convert the variable to a valid javascript object

If you want to have control over which object properties are exposed by the `json_encode` filter you can always implement the interface [`Serializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php)

Comment: Thanks, I will use your first method, It's more 
practice

Comment: I prefer using [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Comment: What has generating a `route` to do with passing `twig variables` into `JS`?

Comment: Path(): Generates a [relative] URL path given a route name and parameters - url(): Generates an absolute URL given a route name and parameters.

Comment: Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?