# If statement with Javascript variable using TWIG

Tags: javascript, twig

Is it possible to write an if statement based on a javascript variable with TWIG?

My first approach was this:

```
{% if info_message is defined %}
    {% include 'includes/alerts/block.html.twig' with {'colorclass': 'danger', 'message': info_message} %}
{% endif %}
```

I want to create an alert based on a javascript variable, so is it possible to fill the `info_message` with javascript and than render it with the message as variable?

I am using alerts like `alerts.block.html.twig`:

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ colorclass }}">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>
{% if raw is defined and raw %}
    {{ message|raw }}
{% else %}
    {{ message }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can't use `javascript` to alter `twig` output. Consider creating a `javascript` variable with your `twig` variable to output the message. Otherwise resort to `ajax`

Comment: @DarkBee so basically what you mean is store the twig info_message in a js var?

Comment: Yes indeed. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-extern-js-file/37606638)