# How to make twig globals accessible in javascript library

Tags: javascript, twig, include

I am refactorizing one twig template, this included a HUGE amount of javascript functions which should be organized into a separate library to keep the structure away from the logic. So i moved them and linked the library like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../global/jscripts/jslibrarytest.js"></script>
```

The problem here is that some of these libraries were using twig globals. Most of the functions work properly, but some others don't.

I've tried passing it through html code and recieving it through jquery (test1) which I couldnt make it work.
Then im trying to access it directly.

My template includes something like this:

```
<div id="twig-vars" data-test="{{ twig_variable }}"></div>
<script>
    $(".boton-excel").click(function() {
          $("#target_data").val(fooFunction);
          alert({{ twig_variable }});
    }); 
</script>
```

external javascript

```
function fooFunction(){
   var test1= $('#twig-vars').data('test');//
   var test2= "{{ twig_variable }}";
   var test3= {{ twig_variable }};//syntax error
   alert(test1);
   alert(test2);
}
```

The output in the alerts was:

1. test 1 => Undefined
2. test 2=> {{ twig_variable }}
3. twig_variable => SUCCESS

Comment: usage of globals is highly discouraged. You should write your libraries in order to not expect them. By the way, if you really need it, attach them to the `window` object and access them by it

Comment: The global im accessing is the common part of a service route. It goes dynamic but has nothing private on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig variable in extern js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-extern-js-file)

Comment: @DarkBee the soltion provided has no example on how the js should be used. Besides even if the main problem is similar the particular case is different.

Comment: Not sure if you even read the answer but the examples are showing you how to convert `twig` variables into `javascript` ones, which then are useable inside external javascript files. The two examples just show you 2 ways to achieve this and don't rely on adding extra `HTML` like your answer.

Comment: I've read that answer before i didnt wrote my question but I am not looking to make more globals but accessing specific ones. The answer by @doydoy44 was more what i was looking for. 
But the problem came somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a bad example above. I was using in my html something more like

```
<div id="twig-vars" data-newRoute="{{ URL_Symfony_dev }}"></div>
```

And so the js was :

```
var test= $('#twig-vars').data('newRoute');
alert(test);
```

Which didn't work. But the problem (camel case in names) couldn't be detected with the example i gave. My apologies
I noticed it after some rewording with data-test worked so i ended up with this in the html.

```
<div id="twig-vars" data-newroute="{{ URL_Symfony_dev }}"></div>
```

And in my JS:

```
var test= $('#twig-vars').data('newroute');
alert(test);
```

And THAT WORKS. 
I am new to this place and i dont know if i should edit the original question. Any help for it also appreciated.

EDIT: Using class(.) instead of id(#) will only capture the first html even if the attribute name is different. This means:

```
<div **class**="twig-vars" data-**test1**="{{ URL_Symfony_dev }}"></div>
<div **class**="twig-vars" data-**test2**="{{ URL_Symfony_dev }}"></div>
<div **class**="twig-vars" data-**test3**="{{ URL_Symfony_dev }}"></div>

var test1= $('.twig-vars').data('test1');
var test2= $('.twig-vars').data('test2');
var test3= $('.twig-vars').data('test3');
alert(test1);//output-> correct result
alert(test2);//output-> undefined
alert(test3);//output-> undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add extra html to pass your variables to twig as seen here

*twig file*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <script>
           var my_route = {% if URL_Symfony_dev is defined %}'{{ URL_Symfony_dev }}'{% else %}null{% endif %}
       </script>
       <script src="scripts/functions.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

*functions.js*

```
$(function() {
    alert('The route is '+my_route);
});
```

Comment: The js scripts libraries are added in a parent library. This means they are forced to be called before i define this "my_route" variable. Maybe this is the reason behind this not working for me. I've tried again just for your efforts but no return at the alert meaning the js cant find the var.

Comment: I'll vote up because it gives me another approach for future cases. So even if it doesnt solves my problem i find it pretty clear to where and how use it on a different scenario

Comment: From your first comment, this means your are loading all your javascript files in your head tag I assume? Do note this delays loading of your webpage

Comment: You're totally right at this, most libraries are invoked at parent, but this one was there. But for my case the code was below. I guess if i moved the src below could work!