# Use Twig variables in external js file

Tags: symfony, webpack, twig, global, external

I am setting up webpack for my symfony project and I want to have page specific javascript files. 
I need to use twig filters such as `{{ form.licenseText.vars.id }}` in my external js file that I will build in webpack.
Any help here?

I tried setting up the variable and calling  tag after that which doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.trumbowyg.svgPath = '/img/trumbowyg-icons.svg';

  var trumbowyg_config = {
    btns: [
      ['formatting'],
      'btnGrp-semantic',
      ['link'],
      ['insertImage'],
      'btnGrp-lists',
      ['horizontalRule'],
      ['removeformat'],
      ['viewHTML'],
      ['fullscreen']
    ]
  };

  $('#{{ form.descriptionText.vars.id }}').trumbowyg(trumbowyg_config);
  $('#{{ form.licenseText.vars.id }}').trumbowyg(trumbowyg_config);

  /* toggle text boxes in respect to the auto update settings */
  $('#{{ form.descriptionTextAutoUpdate.vars.id }}').on('change', function() {
    var au = $('input[name="{{ form.descriptionTextAutoUpdate.vars.full_name }}"]:checked').val() == '1';
    var el = $('#descriptionText_div');
    au ? el.hide() : el.show();
  });
  $('#{{ form.licenseTextAutoUpdate.vars.id }}').on('change', function() {
    var au = $('input[name="{{ form.licenseTextAutoUpdate.vars.full_name }}"]:checked').val() == '1';
    var el = $('#licenseText_div');
    au ? el.hide() : el.show();
  });
```

I would like to access these twig variables in my external js file as shown above in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig variable in extern js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-extern-js-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two tricks for this.

a. Use classes or specific attributes in your form elements, and access to them with global selectors.

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

class MyForm extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
       $builder->add("descriptionText", null, [
           "attr" => [ "class" => ["trumbowygable"]],
           ...
       ]) ;

       ... or ...

       $builder->add("otherField", null, [
           "attr" => [ "data-other-thing" => 1]],
           ...
       ]) 


  }
}
```

And JS looks like ...

```
$('input.trumbowygable').trumbowyg(trumbowyg_config);
// or
$('input[data-other-thing]').on("someEvent", bla bla bla);
```

b. Create a global javascript function that receive id elements by parameters.

```
function buildTrumbowyg(id_one, id_two) {
    $('#' + id_one).blaBlaBla( ... )
}
```

Comment: Used console.log to map for ids and helped. This has a similar implementation as you suggested. Thanks! Another thing I needed to ask is how to access the variables passed to twig from controller in an external javascript file?

Comment: You can make some like `<div class="class" data-twig="{{ myvar|json_decode|e("html_attr") }}">` and your javascript looks like `var xx = $(".class[data-twig]).data("twig");`

Comment: Thanks a ton, this works! Any method to add static yaml files(present locally) to javascript files and compile using webpack, cause import or require doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not expert with webpack. I think you must create another Question with this topíc ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use Ghost input (not displayed) to add variables what you want to value like :

```html
<input type="text" name="your_variable_name" id="your_variable_id" value="{{ your_variable }}" style="display: none;">
```

and after call it in your external javascript like:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
/********/

let variable = $("#your_variable_id").val();

/*********/

});
```