# Data from Twig Variable in _entry.twig to Javascript Function in External Script

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, twig, craftcms

I have created a _layout.twig file which acts as my base to hold content on the page -> _layout.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ craft.app.language }}">
  <head>
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
      {{ siteName }}
    </title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover"
      name="viewport" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
      crossorigin="" />
    {% includeCssFile siteUrl ~ 'assets/css/style.css' %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include '_includes/nav' %}
    <div>
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <footer class="main-footer">
      <div class="footer-wrapper">
        {{ exampleInformation.exampleDescription|markdown }}
        <p>
          &copy; {{ now|date('Y') }}, <a href="https://craftcms.com">Lorem Ipsum</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"   integrity="sha512QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>
    {% includeJsFile siteUrl ~ 'assets/js/scripts.js' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Through the control panel in craft CMS I created an entry  that contains a table that has a series of coordinates (longitude and latitude values) and a lightswitch to toggle it on or off, along with some other general information for each entry that is created e.g. title, date, image, etc. on a separate tab.

The _entry.twig page extends _layout.twig -> _entry.twig:

```
{% extends '_layout' %}

{% set featureImage = {
  mode: 'crop',
  width: 600,
  height: 600,
  quality: 90
} %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="entry__container">
    <div class="entry__wrapper">
      <div class="entry__title">
        <h1>
          {{ entry.title }}
        </h1>
      </div>

      <div class="entry__image">
        {% if entry.featureImage|length %}
          {% for image in entry.featureImage.all() %}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl(featureImage) }}"
              alt="{{ image.title }}" />
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>

      <div>
        {% for block in entry.exampleContent.all() %}
          <div class="entry__description">
            {% if block.type == 'text' %}
              {{ block.text }}
            {% elseif block.type == 'image' %}
              {% for image in block.image.all() %}
                <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>

      {# display post categories #}
      {% if entry.exampleCategories|length %}
        <div class="entry__category">
          <p>
            Categories
          </p>
          {% for category in entry.exampleCategories.all() %}
            <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{- category.title -}}</a>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      {# display table info #}
      {% if entry.lotInfo|length %}
        <div class="entry__coordinate">
          <ul>
            {% for row in entry.lotInfo %}
              {% if row.createNewEntry == '1' %}
                <li>
                  <div data-latCoordinate="{{ row.latitude }}"
                    id="latCoordinate">
                    {{ row.latitude }}
                  </div>,<div data-lngCoordinate="{{ row.longitude }}"
                    id="lngCoordinate">
                    {{ row.longitude }}
                  </div>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      {# end table info #}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I was able to put together this small section in _entry.twig which looks at the table and if the lightswitch is set to 1, it outputs the corresponding latitude and longitude values in the row:

```
{# display table info #}
      {% if entry.lotInfo|length %}
        <div class="entry__coordinate">
          <ul>
            {% for row in entry.lotInfo %}
              {% if row.createNewEntry == '1' %}
                <li>
                  <div data-latCoordinate="{{ row.latitude }}"
                    id="latCoordinate">
                    {{ row.latitude }}
                  </div>,<div data-lngCoordinate="{{ row.longitude }}"
                    id="lngCoordinate">
                    {{ row.longitude }}
                  </div>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      {# end table info #}
```

These values are currently displaying on the front end entry page which will show the coordinates depending on which lightswitch toggle is active- which has allowed me to ensure that it is pulling the correct coordinates corresponding to the correct information.

Now, I have an external js file linked which lives in local/craft/assets/js/*.js and contains this script -> scripts.js:

```
//Set initial map view

var map = L.map('map', { scrollWheelZoom: false }).setView(
  [50.4205, -104.52],
  15,
)

//Initialize the tilemap
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  minZoom: 14.5,
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map)

// Set location array
var locations = [{ lat: 'SOME LATITUDE COORDINATE', lng: 'SOME LONGITUDE COORDINATE' }]

function addToMap(locationArray) {
  //Iterate through array object
  ;[].forEach.call(locationArray, function (location) {
    var marker = L.marker([location.lat, location.lng]).addTo(map)
  })
}
//Show markers
addToMap(locations)
```

Currently, this script will create a leaflet/osm map and then based on:

```
// Set location array
var locations = [{ lat: '(SOME LATITUDE VALUE)', lng: '-(SOME LONGITUDE VALUE') }];
```

will output a marker to the map (currently only works if I manually insert lat and long coordinates) which lives in my index.twig template file -> index.twig:

```
{% extends '_layout' %}
{% set posts = craft.entries.section('example').all() %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="background-test">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <h1 class="example-title">
        Some Title
      </h1>
      <div class="category-list">
        {% set entries = craft.entries.limit(null) %}
        {% for category in craft.categories.relatedTo(entries).order(
          'title asc'
        ) %}
          {% set entryCount = entries.relatedTo(category).total() %}
          <a href="{{ category.url }}">
            {{- category.title -}}<span class="count-number">({{ entryCount }})</span>
          </a>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      {% include '_includes/listing' with {
        posts: posts
      } only %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What would be the best way to somehow use the

```
{{ row.latitude }}, {{ row.longitude }}
```

variables from my _entry.twig file in my existing scripts.js file to place a marker(s) on the map which lives on the index.twig page? I am still new to Craft and more so with Twig so I am still in the process of learning these things.

My folder structure is:

```
/assets
   /css
   /js
      scripts.js
/templates
   /includes
   /blog
      _category.twig
      _entry.twig
       index.twig
   _layout.twig
   index.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig variable in extern js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-extern-js-file)

Comment: Note that the critical part of the duplicate answer is that, if your JS lib expect the `lat, long` as strings and not as int, `{{ row.latitude }}, {{ row.longitude }}` is not equal to `'{{ row.latitude }}', '{{ row.longitude }}'` (mind the quotes `'`!).

Comment: I guess my question is ultimately, how would I pass two variables: {{ row.latitude }}, {{ row.longitude }} defined in my _entry.twig template page which extends _layout.twig to a javascript function located in web/scripts.js?

Comment: Well I've updated my answer in the dupe to provide you two ways

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you for your suggestion! I have looked into that post and unfortunately, I have still had no success. I have updated my question above to include all of the code I currently have along with folder structure to hopefully shed some light on where I am going wrong. Any suggestions you can provide would be much appreciated. Basically, I can get {{ row.latitude }} and {{ row.longitude }} to console.log the values on the entry page itself but can't seem to figure out how to pass them to my external js and display it on the map that is rendered on the index page. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Ok some pointers first, you can add multiple `data-*` attributes to one element, also `id`'s need to be unique. So I'd suggest you'd swap up the twig template to the following:

```html
{% if entry.lotInfo|length %}
<div class="entry__coordinate">
  <ul>
    {% for row in entry.lotInfo %}
      {% if row.createNewEntry == '1' %}
        <li data-latCoordinate="{{ row.latitude }}" data-lngCoordinate="{{ row.longitude }}">
            {{ row.latitude }}, {{ row.longitude }}
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Then we need to adjust your javascript to be able to add multiple dots on the map.
First remove the following line

```js
// Set location array
var locations = [{ lat: 'SOME LATITUDE COORDINATE', lng: 'SOME LONGITUDE COORDINATE' }]
```

As you've defined the pointers in `html` we just need a selector that selects all the elements where the `data-*` attributes are defined in

```js
<script>
document.querySelectorAll(".entry__coordinate ul li").forEach(row => {
    addToMap({ 'lat': row.dataset.latcoordinate, 'lng' : row.dataset.lngcoordinate, });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes and added the script you provided to my_entry.twig page under the reworked section along with removing the 'var locations=[]' from my script.js file. However, it seems there is still a disconnect somewhere. When the _entry. twig page is open it throws errors ' addToMap is not defined' and 'Map container not found' and on the page with the map container _layout.twig throws "locations is not defined" based on my external js file. There still seems to be an issue taking the data from _entry.twig > scripts.js > index.twig (map) where the map container is