# Fetch data from div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twig

I have a list of movies with their infos and what I want to do is to fetch available days with javascript and then add those infos to the div in modal.
This is my code:

```
  <div>
  {% for movie in movies %}
    <div class="movie">
    {{ movie.title.value }}
    <img src="{{ file_url(movie.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}">
    <p>{{ movie.field_description.value }}</p>

    <h3> 'This movie is available on:' </h3>
    <div class="days">
    {% for day in movie.field_days %}
    {{day.entity.label}}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="b" class="bclass" style="visibility:hidden"> Reserve</button>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
   
  </div>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Available days for this movie are:</h4>
    <div class= "modal-body">
     <div class=days></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to fetch {{day.entity.label}} and then add that to the div in modal. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that modal is opened by clicking on Reserve button for example you can add an event on click (if there isn't already one) and you can then find the movie element: `var movie = event.target.closest(".movie");` and then find the days element inside it: `var days = movie.querySelector(".days");" and extract what you need from days.innerHTML

Comment: Hey Gabriel, my Modal is opening with this function: $('.bclass').click(function(){ $('.modal').modal("show");}).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig variable in external JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-external-js-file)

Comment: Ok, here what that function should look like:```$(".bclass").click(function (e) {
  var movie = e.target.closest(".movie");
  var days = movie.querySelector(".days");
  // here you need to parse the string to extract only what you need, for now let's get second line of text
  var extracteddays = days.innerHTML.split("\n");
  console.log(extracteddays);
  $(".modal .days").html(extracteddays[2]);
  $(".modal").modal("show");
});
``` If that is not exactly what it should you will have to add an element to your template day.entity.label so you can get exactly it's value, a span for ex.

Comment: Or if you need all the text from your template <div class="days"> element you can just use (".modal .days").html(days); and not extract the second line

Comment: Gabriel thank you soooo much! I added <span> and I added what you wrote in your second reply $(".modal .days").html(days);  and it works!!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo, i didn't include the modal library, but it doesn't matter, you just need to uncomment that last line, you can see the modal content at the bottom when you click reserve

```js
$(".bclass").click(function (e) {
  var movie = e.target.closest(".movie");
  var days = movie.querySelector(".days");
  $(".modal .days").html(days.innerHTML);
  // $(".modal").modal("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="movie">
    {{ movie.title.value }}
    <img src="{{ file_url(movie.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}">
    <p>{{ movie.field_description.value }}</p>
    <h3> 'This movie is available on:' </h3>
    <div class="days">1 2 3</div>
    <br>
    <button id="b" class="bclass" style=""> Reserve</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div>
  <div class="movie">
    {{ movie.title.value }}
    <img src="{{ file_url(movie.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}">
    <p>{{ movie.field_description.value }}</p>
    <h3> 'This movie is available on:' </h3>
    <div class="days">4 56 6</div>
    <br>
    <button id="b" class="bclass" style=""> Reserve</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Available days for this movie are:</h4>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class=days></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```