# How to get twig data for a JS script

Tags: javascript, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm trying to get data for a `JS` script which is a modal displaying data contained in a `Folder` object

I created a `controller` to display the `Folder` object in a twig view

In my `twig view` I can list each child element (entity) of `Folder` in my `twig view` without any problem:
`bars, bars, quxes`
(boards, categories, elements)

The `Folder` object is displayed as a card html  with tabs for the child elements :
`bars, bars, quxes`
(boards, categories, elements)

In the Tab `Boards` I have a `for loop` that displays the included elements

If I choose one of the elements I open a modal displaying the
`name` and `description`

The question is here :

How to build in Js :
a variable for the `name` of the `Board`: `barname`
and another one for the `description`: `bardescription`
to be read in my modal.

I have already created a twig service "`menubar`" to access the data
I use from a sidebar menu where I display the `Folders` (foo)
To show selected Folder

Controller

```
    #[Route('/folder', name: 'folder_')]
class FooController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/{id}/show', name: 'show', methods: 'GET')]
    public function show(Foo $foo): Response
    {
        return $this->render('foo/show.html.twig', [
            'foo' => $foo,
        ]);
    }
}
```

To Display selected Folder with included elements :
**Boards => Categories => Elements** by Tabs

Twig Tab Boards

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-boards" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-boards-tab">
    <p>
        {% for bar in foo.bars %}

    <p><button type="button" class="alert_demo_2 btn btn-secondary" id="">  {{bar}} </button></p>

        {% endfor %}

    </p>
</div>
```

Button Tab Boards call a Modal via javascript which must contain fields :
Name
and
Description
of the Board

Js

```
<script>

var barname = '{{  }}';
var bardescription = '{{  }}';

  //== Class definition
  var SweetAlert2Demo = function() {

    //== Demo
    var initDemos = function() {

      //== Sweetalert Demo 2
      $('.alert_demo_2').click(function(e) {
        swal(barname, bardescription, {
          buttons: {
            confirm: {
              className : 'btn btn-success'
            }
          }
        });
      });

    return {
      //== Init
      init: function() {
        initDemos();
      }
    };
  }();

  //== Class Initialization
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    SweetAlert2Demo.init();
  });
</script>
```

var **barname** & **bardescription** are twig compatibles variables needed to display the expected data representing :
**name, description**

Modal will display a list of **Boards** found in showed selected **Folder**

Entity Foo (Folder)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\FooRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=FooRepository::class)
*/
class Foo
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
   private ?int $id = null;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   #[Assert\NotBlank]
   private string $name;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
    */
   private $description;

   /**
    * @var Collection<int, Bar>
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Bar::class, mappedBy="foo", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
    */
//    #[Assert\Count(min: 1)]
   #[Assert\Valid]
   private Collection $bars;

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->bars = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   public function __toString()
   {
       return $this->name;
   }

   public function getId(): ?int
   {
       return $this->id;
   }

   public function getName(): ?string
   {
       return $this->name;
   }

   public function setName(string $name): self
   {
       $this->name = $name;

       return $this;
   }

   public function getDescription(): ?string
   {
       return $this->description;
   }

   public function setDescription(?string $description): self
   {
       $this->description = $description;

       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * @return Collection<int, Bar>
    */
   public function getBars(): Collection
   {
       return $this->bars;
   }

   public function addBar(Bar $bar): self
   {
       if (!$this->bars->contains($bar)) {
           $this->bars->add($bar);
           $bar->setFoo($this);
       }

       return $this;
   }

   public function removeBar(Bar $bar): self
   {
       if ($this->bars->removeElement($bar)) {
           if ($bar->getFoo() === $this) {
               $bar->setFoo(null);
           }
       }

       return $this;
   }
}
```

Entity Bar (Board)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BarRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BarRepository::class)
*/
class Bar
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
   private ?int $id = null;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   #[Assert\NotBlank]
   #[Assert\Length(min: 2)]
   private string $name;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
    */
   private $description;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Foo::class, inversedBy="bars")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
   private ?Foo $foo = null;

   /**
    * @var Collection<int, Baz>
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Baz::class, mappedBy="bar", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
    */
//    #[Assert\Count(min: 1)]
   #[Assert\Valid]
   private Collection $bazs;

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->bazs = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   public function __toString()
   {
       return $this->name;
   }

   public function getId(): ?int
   {
       return $this->id;
   }

   public function getName(): ?string
   {
       return $this->name;
   }

   public function setName(string $name): self
   {
       $this->name = $name;

       return $this;
   }

   public function getFoo(): ?Foo
   {
       return $this->foo;
   }

   public function setFoo(?Foo $foo): self
   {
       $this->foo = $foo;

       return $this;
   }

   public function getDescription(): ?string
   {
       return $this->description;
   }

   public function setDescription(?string $description): self
   {
       $this->description = $description;

       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * @return Collection<int, Baz>
    */
   public function getBazs(): Collection
   {
       return $this->bazs;
   }

   public function addBaz(Baz $baz): self
   {
       if (!$this->bazs->contains($baz)) {
           $this->bazs->add($baz);
           $baz->setBar($this);
       }

       return $this;
   }

   public function removeBaz(Baz $baz): self
   {
       if ($this->bazs->removeElement($baz)) {
           // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
           if ($baz->getBar() === $this) {
               $baz->setBar(null);
           }
       }

       return $this;
   }
}
```

DUMP

```
array:3 [▼
  "foo" => App\Entity\Foo {#382 ▼
    -id: 96
    -name: "Design"
    -description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru ▶"
    -bars: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#385 ▼
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: App\Entity\Foo {#382}
      -association: array:15 [ …15]
      -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#246 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "foo"
      -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#360 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#386 ▼
        -elements: []
      }
      #initialized: false
    }
  }
  "app" => Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable {#354 ▶}
  "menubar" => App\Twig\BarsExtension {#342 ▶}
```

Comment: Is this JS script in another file or are you talking about the JS script in the twig file?

Comment: only this part in twig

`var barname = '{{  }}';
var bardescription = '{{  }}';`

this part is called from bottom of base.html.twig :

      `$('.alert_demo_2').click(function(e) {
        swal(barname, bardescription, {
          buttons: {
            confirm: {
              className : 'btn btn-success'
            }
          }
        });
      });
`

Comment: this work but only for the index [0] element :
`var barname = ['{{ foo.bars[0].name }}'];
 var bardescription = ['{{ foo.bars[0].description }}'];`
i need a loop..

Comment: Yes, According to your annotations in ``Foo`` entity, it has a ``OneToMany`` relationship with ``Bar`` entity. So when you access the ``foo.bars`` it returns an array of ``Bar`` entities.

Comment: indeed yes  Dula
i just need to understand how to do a for loop in js like in Twig ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig variable in external JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-external-js-file)

Comment: Not really DarkBee  :-)
I had tried without success
tk's

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the linked question I've marked as dupe, you can pass data from twig to javascript with the aid of `data-*` attributes. Change your template to something like the following

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-boards" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-boards-tab">
{% for bar in foo.bars %}
    <button type="button" class="alert_demo_2 btn btn-secondary" data-name="{{ bar.getName() }}" data-description="{{ bar.getDescription() }}">{{ bar.getName() }}</button>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

By adding these attributes you are now able to use them inside javascript

```js
$(document).on('click', '.alert_demo_2', function(e) {
    swal($(this).data('name'), $(this).data('description'), {
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                className : 'btn btn-success'
            }
        }
    });
});
```